# Python: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'privileges' - How do I debug the code?

Tags: python

```
class user():
    # This creates the two attributes called first_name and last_name and other attributes e.g. email and username
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email, username ):
            self.first_name = first_name
            self.last_name = last_name
            self.email = email
            self.username = username
            self.login_attempts = 0
            

    # This method describe_user prints a summary of the user’s information. 
    def describe_user(self):
        print(f'Name: {self.first_name} {self.last_name}')
        print(f'Username: {self.username}')
        print(f'email: {self.email}')

    # This method greet user prints a personalized greeting to the user.
    def greet_user(self):
        print(f'Welcome back {self.first_name}')

class Admin(user):

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, email, username, privileges ):
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, email, username)
        self.privileges = privileges

    # Creates method called show_privileges
    def show_privileges(self):
        print('Your admin privileges are:')
        for priv in self.privileges:
            print(f'      - {priv}')

privs = ['can add post', 'can delete post', 'can ban user']
gold = Admin('Peter', 'Gold', 'pgold@collin.edu', privs)


gold.show_privileges()
gold.describe_user()
```

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the username argument when creating the instance of the Admin class
`gold = Admin('Peter', 'Gold', 'pgold@collin.edu', privs)` should be `gold = Admin('Peter', 'Gold', 'pgold@collin.edu', 'username', privs)`

To make this a little more useful and actually answers the question. You're exception traceback has a line number attached to it which, in this case, was the `gold = Admin('Peter', 'Gold', 'pgold@collin.edu', privs)`. The **init**() missing 1 required positional argument 'privileges' is saying that a class is being created, but the **init**() of the class has more arguments than provided. In this case, it's putting the `privs` variable in the `username` spot (due to order) so it thinks that `privileges` is missing.

Comment: Thank you so so much...New to programming...been on it for long ...checked other responses to no avail....didn't see it till now thanks. Now I know that an omission from an argument can through up a 'Type' error too! Hope this helps someone else

Comment: When you have a long list of arguments and they're all the same type, I highly recommend using keywords instead of just typing out the arguments.  If you had written `Admin(first_name="Peter", last_name="Gold", email="pgold", privs=privs)`, Python would have given you a much better error message.  And your code is also clearer!